# Developer asking for my keystore and passwords

Tags: google-play-console, android-keystore

I am the owner of multiple apps on google play. I have a keystore for each app. Now I am outsourcing to a developer and this person is also helping me with stuff on google play developer console such as in-app purchases. He is now saying he needs the keystore and the related passwords to sign a release. I do not want to share those for security reasons. What should I do in this case? is there any workaround to allow him to continue working without sharing keystore and credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can perform the release yourself. After all you just have to compile the code and sign it. (I asume you use GIT).
2. You could use the Google App Sign, the signing data it's hosted in your google developer account and not in an external keystore, each time you upload an update google play will sign it. Take a look at this please: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: Thank you Bogdan. How do I configure my gradle file to use Google App sign-in instead of keystore credentials? I could not find any documentation.

Comment: There is a complete tutorial at the link I posted in my answer, check the sub-menu "alredy published apps"

Comment: it just says: "Use your new upload key to sign releases before you upload them to Google Play" but does not provide more details. In my case I am using building a flutter app and I do not have this option on Android Studio. It only uses gradle file if I understand well. :( any ideas?